# Error while fetching sub-list from MySQL Database using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, content-management-system

## Intention

I'm trying to fetch sub-list inside the main list.

### Error

This  appears on my web page**.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
> syntax to use near 'ORDER BY subject_id ASC' at line 1

### Code:

```
       <ul class="subjects">
 <?php
 //db query
 $query ="SELECT * FROM  `subjects` ";
 $query.="WHERE visible = 1 ";
 $query.="ORDER BY position ASC";
 $subject_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
 confirm_query($subject_set); ?>
 <?php while($subject=mysqli_fetch_assoc($subject_set))    
 {
 ?>
 <li>
 <?php
 echo $subject['menu_name'];
 } ?> 
 
 <?php
 $query ="SELECT * FROM  `pages` ";
 $query.="WHERE visible = 1 ";
 $query.="AND subject_id ={$subject["id"]}";
 $query.="ORDER BY subject_id ASC";
 $page_set= mysqli_query($connection, $query);
 echo mysqli_error($connection);
 confirm_query($page_set);
 ?>
 <ul class="pages">
 <?php
 while($page= mysqli_fetch_assoc($page_set)){
 ?>
 <li>
 <?php echo $page['menu_name'];?>
 </li><!---page_ul,li-->
 <?php
 } 
 mysqli_free_result($page_set);
 ?>
 </ul><!--pages_ul-->
 </li>
 </div><!--navigation-->
 </ul><!--ul-subjects-->
 <?php 
 mysqli_free_result($page_set);
 ?>
 </div>
```

Comment: try to add space after your curly brackets like this     `$query.="AND subject_id ={$subject["id"]}   ";`

Comment: You really need to start indenting your code. Reading this is killing my eyes!

Answer (score 0):

Problem is at line 20, where `"` are nested. I've indented your code to make it readable.

Another error revealed after indentation is wrong `while` cycles nesting.

```
<ul class="subjects">
    <?php
    //db query
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM  `subjects` ';
    $query .= 'WHERE visible = 1 ';
    $query .= 'ORDER BY position ASC';
    $subject_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    confirm_query($subject_set);
    while ($subject = mysqli_fetch_assoc($subject_set)) { ?>
        <li>
            <?php
            echo $subject['menu_name'];

            $query = 'SELECT * FROM  `pages` ';
            $query .= 'WHERE visible = 1 ';
            $query .= 'AND subject_id = "' . $subject['id']. '" ';
            $query .= 'ORDER BY subject_id ASC';
            $page_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
            echo mysqli_error($connection);
            confirm_query($page_set);
            ?>
            <ul class="pages">
                <?php
                while ($page = mysqli_fetch_assoc($page_set)) {
                    ?>
                    <li>
                        <?php echo $page['menu_name']; ?>
                    </li>
                    <?php
                }
                mysqli_free_result($page_set);
                ?>
            </ul>
        </li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for this help.
But, the real problem remains same. Even if I give space, it still gives me the same error. I have given space then removed it, the error is stiff and hard like not to move a cm.

Comment: Problem is definetly at line 20, I've edited it to make it clear.  Try 

      `$query .= 'AND subject_id = ' . $subject['id']. ' ';`

Comment: Doing it this way, gives no error but, the sub list
unordered list inside a list is not being fetched. 
$query.=" AND subject_id = ' { $subject [ " id " ]} '  ";

Comment: Is  `$subject [ " id " ]` an integer value?

Comment: @J. Doe, what output do you have, when inside list is not being fetched?

Comment: I've working all over but, still the problem exists with the WHERE clause

Comment: If I comment this 
//$query .= 'AND subject_id = "$subject['id']";
I get the navigation in output as
About Widget_Corp
Products
Services
Today's Widget Trivia
//this is the sub-list
    Our Mission
    Our History
    Largest Widgets
    Small Widgets
    Retrofitting
    Certification 
the sub-list should be like
About Widget_Corp
    Our Mission
    Our History
Products
Largest Widgets
    Small Widgets
Services
    Retrofitting
    Certification 
Today's Widget Trivia

Comment: @J. Doe, try to change that commented line to that, I propose in my answer: `$query .= 'AND subject_id = "' . $subject['id']. '"';`

Comment: Still having error. Can you help me working with SQL in regards of foreign key. Actually the subject_id is 'id' in `pages` while $subject['id'] is the 'id' is from `subjects` table. 

I want Main List from `subjects` table
and then its sub-list from `pages` table where the subject id will be equal to the id of Main List.

Comment: The error reflects as "Check your SQL syntax near ORDER BY subject_id ASC"
I feel like the foreign key actually is creating problem. I mean the $subject['id'] because when I comment the line of WHERE clause if executes and fetches the data

Comment: @J. Doe, could you write here an SQL query sample, you trying to execute? Without any php code. Is it `SELECT * FROM  pages WHERE visible = 1 AND subject_id = 1 ORDER BY subject_id ASC`. Does this query show error?

Comment: Not coming in the right position. Actually some problem is with subject_id = {$subject['id']};